# Can I add more than one value for a key in Firebase?

Tags: android, database, firebase

In the data which I can enter in firebaseio.com URL given to me, there is one value to a key. Is there a way to add more values to a key and also wanted to know how to retrieve and read such data using Android Studio.

Thank You

Comment: Yes, that is definitely possible. I recommend going over the [Firebase guide for Android developers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide) and this [codelab for Android developers](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/codelabs/chat).

Answer (score 1):

On the Firebase editor click the green + sign (don't put any value) to create another level which will let you put multiple key-value pairs under one key.

When you use the API (java or other) you can post an object with multiple fields to a key to achieve what you asked for.